# Overlapping image slow crossfade on bootstrap carousel fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to achieve a smooth overlapping image fade like [this](http://www.1squarepear.com/_docs/bootstrap_carousel_fade.html?) which I grabbed from the demo button at the bottom of [here](http://www.1squarepear.com/adding-a-responsive-bootstrap-image-carousel-that-fades-instead-of-slides/). I can't seem to get their code working for me so i've been using [this](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/ZkRvj) code and attempting to edit it get the fade I want rather than how its fading to white then the next image. I also want to make the transitions between the images slower and the time spent on each image longer.

EDIT: I tried editing the code to 
css

```
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item  {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: 5s opacity ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: 5s opacity ease-in-out; 
        -ms-transition: 5s opacity ease-in-out; 
         -o-transition: 5s opacity ease-in-out; 
            transition: 5s opacity ease-in-out; 
    left:0 !important;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .active{
    opacity:1;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .active.left,
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .active.right {
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:1;
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1, 
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2,
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339134316-0e91dc9ded92?q=75&fm=jpg&s=883a422e10fc4149893984019f63c818); 
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339684178-3a239570f315?q=75&fm=jpg&s=c39d9a3bf66d6566b9608a9f1f3765af);
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339276121-ba1dfa199912?q=75&fm=jpg&s=9bf9f2ef5be5cb5eee5255e7765cb327);
}
```

html

```
<div class="carousel fade-carousel carousel-fade slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="8000" id="bs-carousel">
  <!-- Overlay -->
  <div class="overlay"></div>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item slides active">
      <div class="slide-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

still can't seem to get the images to crossfade

Answer (score 0):

#### update your HTML `data-interval="4000"` this is the period between each img:

`<div class="carousel fade-carousel carousel-fade slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000" id="bs-carousel">`

#### update your CSS those `2s` to `4s` or whatever, this is the time for the text to fade in / fade out:

```
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item .hero {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item.active .hero {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;    
}
```

```css
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: opacity;
  -o-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}

.fade-carousel {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item {
  height: 100vh;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators>li {
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #f39c12;
  border-color: #f39c12;
  opacity: .7;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators>li.active {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}


/********************************/


/*          Hero Headers        */


/********************************/

.hero {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

.hero h1 {
  font-size: 6em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item .hero {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 1s all ease-in-out .1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s all ease-in-out .1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s all ease-in-out .1s;
  -o-transition: 1s all ease-in-out .1s;
  transition: 1s all ease-in-out .1s;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item.active .hero {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 1s all ease-in-out .1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s all ease-in-out .1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s all ease-in-out .1s;
  -o-transition: 1s all ease-in-out .1s;
  transition: 1s all ease-in-out .1s;
}


/********************************/


/*            Overlay           */


/********************************/

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #080d15;
  opacity: .7;
}


/********************************/


/*          Custom Buttons      */


/********************************/

.btn.btn-lg {
  padding: 10px 40px;
}

.btn.btn-hero,
.btn.btn-hero:hover,
.btn.btn-hero:focus {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  border-color: #1abc9c;
  outline: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
}


/********************************/


/*       Slides backgrounds     */


/********************************/

.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1,
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2,
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339134316-0e91dc9ded92?q=75&fm=jpg&s=883a422e10fc4149893984019f63c818);
}

.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339684178-3a239570f315?q=75&fm=jpg&s=c39d9a3bf66d6566b9608a9f1f3765af);
}

.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339276121-ba1dfa199912?q=75&fm=jpg&s=9bf9f2ef5be5cb5eee5255e7765cb327);
}


/********************************/


/*          Media Queries       */


/********************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  .hero {
    width: 980px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .hero h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="carousel fade-carousel carousel-fade slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="6000" id="bs-carousel">
  <!-- Overlay -->
  <div class="overlay"></div>

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item slides active">
      <div class="slide-1"></div>
      <div class="hero">
        <hgroup>
          <h1>We are creative</h1>
          <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
        </hgroup>
        <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">See all features</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-2"></div>
      <div class="hero">
        <hgroup>
          <h1>We are smart</h1>
          <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
        </hgroup>
        <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">See all features</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-3"></div>
      <div class="hero">
        <hgroup>
          <h1>We are amazing</h1>
          <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
        </hgroup>
        <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">See all features</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but I couldn't get the images to crossfade. I didn't need the text or indicators so I deleted all the .hero from css and html along with the indicators in the css and html. I rewrote the code too but still cannot get it to work.